# Convert pandas unicode column to timestamp python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, unicode

I am getting:

```
TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'unicode'
```

When I try to do this:

```
df = df[df['timestamp'] >= start]
df = df[df['timestamp'] < (end + timedelta(days=1))]
```

The data types are:

```
type(df['timestamp'][0])
Out[134]: unicode
type(start)
Out[135]: pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp
```

So, I have been trying to convert the column to a pandas datetime. I do the following and it is still a unicode data type.

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s', errors='coerce')
```

Comment: I think the problem is not the left-hand side, but the right-hand side.

Comment: Could you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It appears you were correct. I put pd.to_datetime(start) and there was no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says:

> ```
> TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'unicode'
> ```

So that means you made a comparison, with `Timestamp` on the left side, and `unicode` on the right side (given the error occurs of course at the comparison level).

Since the error occurs at:

```
df = df[df['timestamp'] >= start]
```

This thus means that `start` is a `unicode` string, not a timestamp.

You thus first need to convert `start`, for example with:

```
df = df[df['timestamp'] >= pd.to_datetime(start)]
```

Comment: Exactly what I did. Thanks for explaining/answering